# Return the best model (from a group of models) R for Automation

Tags: r, automation, linear-regression

I have developed 3 models in R. I want to select the best model and use that model for prediction. Here is some imaginary data:

```
data <- data.frame(x = seq(1, 10, by = 0.1), y = seq(11, 20, by = 0.1), z= seq(21,30, by = 0.1))

test_data <- data.frame(x = seq(101, 110, by = 0.1), y = seq(111, 120, by = 0.1), z= seq(121,130, by = 0.1))

model1 <- lm(y~x, data = data)
model2 <- lm(y~z, data = data)
model3 <- lm(y~ x + z, data = data)
```

I want to then compare the accuracy of all models and save the model with highest accuracy as the one I will use for prediction. I am having trouble figuring out this part, could not get a start.

```
best_model <- "Model with best accuracy- **Need Help Here**"
caret::predict(best_model, test_data_set)
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Models with more predictors are always going to be closer to the actual values even if you just add random noise. There are stepwise selection algorithms but aren't always considered best practices. Evaluating which model is "best" is really a statistical problem, not a programming problem. If you need statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead.